# create certificate for IIS 7.0 issue

Tags: iis, iis-7, https, certificate

I am configuring https for IIS 7.0 and I need to create a test certificate for IIS 7.0 server. I am new to create certificate for IIS 7.0, and I only need server certificate, no need for client certificate.

I am configuring IIS 7.0 on my Windows Vista Enterprise.

Any recommended readings or documents?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx) has an excellent walkthrough for creating a self signed certificate in IIS 7 and assigning it to your site.

Answer (score 0):

try to use x509Builder web application at http://www.we-coffee.com/x509builder.aspx